# What is the unit of measure used to specify the width of the columns of the DevExpress GridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I have a WinForm application with a DevExpress GridView. I have set the width of each column manually in the designer, but they doesn't seen to have followed the sizes I have set. I thought the width might was measured in pixels.

I think the Grid is resizing the columns in some random way.

Comment: The grid probably has an auto size property of some sort, you'll need to disable it.

Comment: I have set OptionsView.ColumnAutoWidth to false, but to no avail.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know the `DevExpress` components very well, but generally speaking with those types of components those properties are at *many levels* and you have to find the right level.

Comment: When I set this property to false, it made some effect, the grid was not scrolling horizontally, now it is scrolling, but the sizes are not correct anyway.

Comment: have you tried playing with the Layout of the Grid View? You can set column width from Layout Tab (when you Run Designer)

Comment: Well, the only properties of the grid I have changed are: EnableMasterViewMode = false, ShowIndicator = false, ShowGroupPanel = false. I'm drawing a checkbox dynamically in one column header, but I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: @Pavlov, it worked! It's strange that setting by the designer layout tab it works, but setting manually don't. But it solved my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the Column width using the Layout Tab on DevExpress Designer.